# How to correctly define a decorator?

Tags: javascript

I found this decorator [example](https://survivejs.com/react/appendices/understanding-decorators/).

Why does it throw an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

And where does the third argument "descriptor" come from, why does it have a .value?

```
class Math {
  @log
  add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }
}

function log(target, name, descriptor) {
  var oldValue = descriptor.value;

  descriptor.value = function() {
    console.log(`Calling "${name}" with`, arguments);

    return oldValue.apply(null, arguments);
  };

  return descriptor;
}

const math = new Math();

// passed parameters should get logged now
math.add(2, 4);
```

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: No I just found this code snippet, thought it is pure js

Comment: Decorators are only in Stage 2 (https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators). You can use them with a transpiler like Babel, but not vanilla. The descriptor is the actual function / class

Comment: `Math` is a bad name. It will clash with the global `Math` ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be using them with a transpiler.

Answer (score 0):

Decorators are currently a draft proposal (see https://tc39.es/proposal-decorators/).

Besides that, your current code is using the legacy syntax. If you go to babel and enable the relevant flags (stage-2 and legacy decorator syntax) it works.

See [babel example](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAECyYBcAW0DeAoa0ACID2A5ptGACakAUYANNAEYCUaxWATgKYICurAdidADU9ANzEAvuknoAZl17AEASzz98BCgjCsCnWrzABbdrVLsIwVkoAOCPKyYYsAN23Q8IUgDUwILu2gAXmgzCytbewA6Vz92MWJQyxs7VmjffyDoOQVlVQpHFmhgVQgPdkj1CgADAGFfECVeAmgAIgASVANjcRboAHclZCrabQIuY14ECAZ4rDZOHn4Pb3TysGtrEABPCl4uEBARnXH2SemxLHFZ6A5uPhDzJIjWMWli3ggEaENEFGDedh9OC_fLxAD0YOg1kgEHYpCh2iMnHYrBgECQeH28N0X3UunhvDwfXQP2QkTIlAATLQACwzIA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Cstage-2&prettier=true&targets=&version=7.5.4&externalPlugins=) and open the console